# How to write this Angular HTML using only one <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="channel in Board.Channels">
            <a ng-if="channel.key == ''" ng-href="/{{Board.type}}/{{Board.id}}/{{Board.key}}">{{channel.title}}</a>
            <a ng-if="channel.key != ''" ng-href="/{{Board.type}}/{{Board.id}}/{{Board.key}}?channel={{channel.key}}">{{channel.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The only difference between the two links is one has a query parameter, and the other does not.

Is there a way to write this without using two `<a ng-if="">` condition tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An angular binding `{{}}` can contain code or scope variables. In this case you can use angular's awkward ternary operator for binds: `{{boolean && ifTrueValue || ifFalseValue}}` which you could read as being similar to `(boolean) ? ifTrueValue : ifFalseValue`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="channel in Board.Channels">
        <a ng-href="/{{Board.type}}/{{Board.id}}/{{Board.key}}{{(channel.key == '') && ''|| '?channel='+ channel.key}}">{{channel.title}}<span class="cgCount">{{channel.count}}</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1. I didn't know you could write the expression directly in a binding like that. I thought it had to be done outside of a `{{}}` capture. thanks.

Comment: Cheers, I have struggled through the Angular docs, which wasn't friendly to me being new to web development in general. They are OK as docs but the true gems of Angular's functionality are found in SO questions and blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a bit, but I figured it out.

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="channel in Board.Channels" ng-init="query= channel.key != '' && '/?channel='+channel.key || ''">
            <a ng-href="/{{Board.type}}/{{Board.id}}/{{Board.key}}{{query}}">{{channel.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Angular doesn't support `?:` operator in expressions, but it does allow you to do these boolean results as above.

Comment: A simultaneous answers, do check out my one above as Angular does have an awkward ternary operator, though there was supposed to be a proper one in future versions, not sure if that ever happened though. See this post on more helpful Angular 'quirks' http://blog.tomaka17.com/2012/12/random-tricks-when-using-angularjs/